# FTP From Local Desktop to Server As Sudo User

Tags: linux, ftp, filezilla

I have a file on my desktop that I need to FTP to a server. As I've been navigating this server, I need to login with initial credentials to access the box and then needed to run `sudo -u [username] ksh` to access the folder I need. (No password)

In Filezilla however, I only enter credentials once and therefore, don't have the option to sudo as the user and get permissions to the folder.

Am I going about this process wrong and if so, what's the usual way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to switch user on the ftp protocol. You need to know the correct credentials in the first place.

The closest you could come would be to ftp the files to a directory you do have access to, log in with a shell, and then move the files using shell commands after switching user.